# Separate license needed for Visual Studio 2012 SQL Server database projects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssdt, visual-studio, database-projects

We have SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition and would like to use Visual Studio 2012 Database Projects for version control.

Do we need to purchase a license to use VS database projects? Or is it included with our standard edition license; we just have to download it separately?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a licensing question that should be worked out with Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a special SQL Server license to use Visual Studio database projects. As mentioned in [srutzky's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/135320/72091) the database projects are driven by [SSDT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx) which is a free download.

If you are willing to use a newer version of Visual Studio than 2012, and you want to use a database project within Visual Studio then you should consider [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-community-vs). As you can see in the "Muliple languages" section you can choose a "SQL Server" project type/template which is the database project.

[image: templates screenshot]

As far as I recall none of the free versions of Visual Studio 2012 allowed you to create database projects. That means if you're committed to using Visual Studio 2012 to create/manage/etc. your database project then you'll need to buy an appropriate license for the version of Visual Studio 2012 you want to use.

---

Note the licensing restrictions are at the bottom of the Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition that I linked to above. The cliff notes version **at the time of writing this answer** is:

- Individuals

  > Any individual developer can use Visual Studio Community to create their own free or paid apps.
- Companies

  > An unlimited number of users within an organization can use Visual Studio Community for the following scenarios: in a classroom learning environment, for academic research, or for contributing to open source projects.
  >
  > In non-enterprise organizations, up to five users can use Visual Studio Community. In enterprise organizations (meaning those with >250 PCs or >$1 Million US Dollars in annual revenue), no use is permitted beyond the open source, academic research, and classroom learning environment scenarios described above.

The [full license terms are found here](https://www.visualstudio.com/support/legal/mt171547).

Answer (score 2):

I think you mean SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools) which handles Visual Studio Database projects, but can be run independently of Visual Studio.

Look into the documentation for SSDT. Start here:

[Download SQL Server Data Tools (SSDT)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx)

Also might want to look here:

[SQL Server Data Tools Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ssdt/)